Software based energy meter
I have been implementing a software energy meter. In other words my software has to integrate immediate electrical power over time. The immediate electrical power is calculated based on following equation
$$
p(k) = v(k)\cdot i(k),
$$
where $v(k)$, $i(k)$ are the samples of voltage and current at a given time instant. My question is whether I should filter the calculated immediate electrical power via some appropriate low pass filter before integration or it's redundat due to the fact that the
integrator itself is a sort of low pass filter.


due to the fact that the integrator itself is a sort of low pass filter.

Correct (more or less).
$p[k]$ is the instantaneous power (which can also be negative !) and by it's very definition, the energy consumed (or generated) on the time interval $[n_1,n_2]$ is
$$E_{1_2} = \Delta T \cdot \sum_{n = n_1}^{n_2-1} p[n] $$
where $\Delta T$ is your sampling interval and we assume that $p[n]$ is has units of Watts.
There may be use cases for a low-pass filter (mostly for cosmetic reasons) but that depends on your specific application: how jumpy is your power signal, how "correct" does it need to be (say for billing purposes), do you care about "easy readability", etc.
There is one less obvious pitfall here: Let's assume that both voltage and current wave forms are bandlimited at a max frequency of $f_0$ and and are sampled alias-free at a sample rate slightly higher than $2f_0$. Multiplication will double the bandwidth so the instantaneous power signal has a max frequency of $2f_0$ and you are at risk of aliasing if you directly multiply the discrete voltage and current signals.
There two ways around this. A) do a spectral analysis to determine if this is a problem or can be ignored. B) up-sample voltage and current by a factor of 2 before multiplying.
